# Why am I no more able to change the environment variable $USERNAME on macOS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, zsh, iterm2, direnv

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

```
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
$ export USERNAME=newvalue
$ echo $USERNAME
newvalue
```

**WHAT IS HAPPENING**

```
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
$ export USERNAME=newvalue
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

- I tried to use: `sudo` ...;
- I tried to use: `unset USERNAME`.

**USEFUL NOTES**

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14
- Direnv: https://github.com/direnv/direnv
- I am using `zsh`

**WHAT I DID BEFORE THE ISSUE**

I was able to change my environment variable several times using `direnv` (https://github.com/direnv/direnv), and everything was working well.

I was able to set local env variables in `.envrc`. 
Then, I encountered this issue...

---

**SOLUTION**

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483469/cannot-change-the-environment-variable

Answer (score 10):

In zsh the `USERNAME` var is magical. It is not a normal exported env var. From the man page:

```
   USERNAME <S>
          The username corresponding to the real user ID of the shell process.  If you
          have sufficient privileges, you may change the username (and also  the  user
          ID  and group ID) of the shell by assigning to this parameter.  Also (assum-
          ing sufficient privileges), you may start a single command under a different
          username (and user ID and group ID) by `(USERNAME=username; command)'
```

In other shells, like bash and fish, this is not a special var and you can set it just like any other env var:

```
bash$ echo $USERNAME

bash$ export USERNAME=wtf
bash$ echo $USERNAME
wtf
```